# SQL calculating percentage and list of top ten regions

Tags: sql

I need help. I have these tables.

1. Patient (PatienID, names, gender, address, contact, occupation, doctorID, userID, registrarID)
2. Diagnosis (DiagnosisID, Provissional_Diagnosis, Alternative_Diagnosis, Definitive_Diagnosis, PatientID, DoctorID)
3. Treatment (TreatmenI, Medicine, Dosage, Type, Councelling, DiagnosisID)

So I want to write the following queries

1. What is the percentage of patients that have previously suffered from 'Malaria' were treated for Malaria in the future?
2. List the top 10 regions with the highest number of Malaria cases.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.

Comment: School assignment? Show us what you've tried.

Comment: For 2) see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+greatest-n-per-group

Comment: I'm confused , i don't know how start ..